# Compiling Java Program with .jar file and different packages

Tags: java, jar, compilation, package

I have this code, in where I have 'jar' file that I use as a library. And in my "src" I have multiple packages with ".java" files in them.
I am highly confused about how to compile and run this program on terminal.
I have attached an image of the directory.

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfg22v9y78yndan/DirecotryPic.png

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a jar file in the src folder??
You should be referencing them from Java build path. Right click on your project -> Java Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries. 
Add your library files here. Not in the src.

From the picture it seems you are using eclipse IDE. Eclipse builds the file automatically. From the Menu bar click Project and make sure you checked Build Automatically.
To run this on the terminal, export this whole project as Runnable Jar and from terminal execute this "java -jar yourproject.jar"

Right click on project -> Export -> Runnable Jar.

Is it what you are looking for???

Comment: I see that I have DirectoryServer.jar in my src by mistake, I will take that out.
What I am asking is, that I want to compile this code on a remote system; I have to do that by terminal (its an UNIX system) using a script ".sh'.
Now, I have "DD.jar" and packages "data", encoders&Decoders", and "storage" and I need these to run my "DirectoryServer.java".
I want to know that what should I write in that script?
For example:
#!/bin/sh
javac -classpath "JAR FILES AND PACKAGES HERE" DirectoryServer.java
Script to run:
#!/bin/sh
java -classpath DirectoryServer.jar:DD.jar DirectoryServer
I am confused

Answer (score 0):

*First of all: JAR files should not be copied to the src folder. As far as I can see DirectoryServer.jar is in it right now.
Secondly: .sh files should be moved to the root of your project too.*

You could easily generate Ant buildfiles with Eclipse (Export.. > Ant buildfiles) and then use them from terminal (installing ANT is a must!).

Other option would be to export a runnable JAR directly from Eclipse, then run it from terminal.

I hope it helps! Feel free to ask in comment if you have any more questions!

Comment: I see that I have DirectoryServer.jar in my src by mistake, I will take that out.
What I am asking is, that I want to compile this code on a remote system; I have to do that by terminal (its an UNIX system) using a script ".sh'.
Now, I have "DD.jar" and packages "data", encoders&Decoders", and "storage" and I need these to run my "DirectoryServer.java".
I want to know that what should I write in that script?
For example:
#!/bin/sh
javac -classpath "JAR FILES AND PACKAGES HERE" DirectoryServer.java
Script to run:
#!/bin/sh
java -classpath DirectoryServer.jar:DD.jar DirectoryServer
I am confused

Comment: I see now. You should check out [this](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/) tutorial. It will show you how to complie application from command line. Still, I'd use Ant (or other alternatives) to compile your application instead of simple shell scripts. Here is a nice [tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) for Ant, if you are interested.